# How do I load URL that requires login into variable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to port my usage meter from a JavaScript Gadget (win) / Widget (OSX) to Android. Total newbie when comes to JAVA + Eclipse + Android 2.1 SDK. Essentially what I want to do is load a page, pass through a username and password and load the resulting page into a array that I can then run some regular expressions through.

My code from JavaScript (I've replace the actual URL with a dummy one) is:

```
xmlhttp.open("post","https://acme.com.au/your_account/index.php?function=login",false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("check_username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
```

I need to know the Android equivalent to the above please. I've played around with WebView but that loads the page in a web browser which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to include a third party library, you could somthing along the lines below:

```
URL url = new URL("https://acme.com.au/your_account/index.php?function=login");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// If you need a cookie from previous requests
//conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + encode(jSessionId, "UTF-8")); 
conn.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(String.format("check_username=%s&password=%s",
        URLEncoder.encode(PERSNR, "UTF-8"),
        URLEncoder.encode(PASSWD, "UTF-8")));

out.close();

// I have absolutely no idea why this is needed.
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
// ... read the response from is.
is.close();
```

However I encourage you to use some third party library for anything less trivial than this. I use Apache HttpClient in my Android widget :)

Comment: Great thanks, I'll give it a try. Would the syntax be simpier if I use the Apache HttpClient?

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html). The main benefit as I see it however, is the maturity of the code. I guarantee you that you'll have fewer bugs to fix if you leverage a well tested library to do the task.

Comment: Great. This example seems to be exactly what I am after: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java.

Just one question though, on Android, where does System.out.println send the output? I've tried it in the past but nothing appears on the device?

Comment: Actually figured our the println issue but I am stuck with getting the actual page contents. All I seem to be able to get are status messages like "HTTP/1.1 200 OK". I want to see the contents of the page instead.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question since these comments don't really work well with code-formatting and so on. Feel free to drop a link to the follow-up quetion here in the comments though :)

Comment: I've managed to get it to work. 8-) Was missing a responsehandler. I now have a problem using REGEX which I'll post in a new question